# Using the generic type parameter vs using its type constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have a class structure like this, where class `Foo` is a generic over a class hierarchy of `Base`, `Derived1`, etc.

```
abstract class Base {...}

class Derived1 : Base {...}

.
.
.

class Derivedn : Base {...}


class Foo<T> where T : Base
{
   /// XXX is a placeholder - see below
   void DoBar(XXX arg) {...}
   ...
}
```

Wanting `DoBar()` to operate on *something derived from `Base`*, **does it make any difference if `XXX` is `Base` or is `T` ?**

The constraint means that `T` has to be `Base` or one of its children; but within the scope of `DoBar()` it is going to treat it as an object of type `Base` either way -- so this seems superficially like it will make no difference. But I might be overlooking something more subtle.

Answer (score 4):

If you set `xxx` to `Base` than your method parameter can be `Base` or any class derived from `Base`.
If you set `xxx` to `T` than your method parameter can be `T` class or any class derived from `T`.

So if you instantiate `Foo` class with the generic type of `Derived1` for example, in the first case you can use `Base` or classes derived from `Base` and in the second case you can use only `Derived1` or classes derived from `Derived1`